# Align the two <p> element in the same line

Tags: html, css

This is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/knQc6/).

I want to align the two `<p>` element in the same line, but you can see the second one moves down a little bit.  Anybody knows the reason?

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo">
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <p class="web_address">Hello all</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inline(-block) elements (the paragraphs in this case) are aligned vertically in their **baseline** by default. You could add [`vertical-align: top;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) to fix the alignment issue.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/knQc6/1/)**.

```css
.logo p {
    /* other styles goes here... */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

For further details you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278).

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` might be a better solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zxefz/

```
<div class="logo">
    <span>Hello world</span>
    <span class="web_address">Hello all</span>
</div>

.logo{
    height: 80px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.logo span{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 36px;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 80px;
}

.logo .web_address{
    font-size:26px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me:

```css
.toptext {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="toptext">
  <p>Please ensure all original documents requested are enclosed</p>
  <p id="right">Claim Reference No.: <input type="text" name="" value=""></p>
</div>
```