# Text inside div displaces other divs

Tags: html, css, layout

I have placed 3 divs next to each other using the block-inline property.

When I add text inside the div that exceeds the divs width, it will displace surrounding divs by shifting them down slightly.

```
<div class="explained_container">
    <div class="explained_c-1">Why does text in this div displace the other divs</div>
    <div class="explained_c-2">Div 2</div> 
    <div class="explained_c-3">Div 3</div> 
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle I created to present the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/32E8m/

Comment: you need to define a float value for the divs, like `div { float: left }` see forked fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/32E8m/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [two inline-block div with different font-size, can't be in the exact same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405858/two-inline-block-div-with-different-font-size-cant-be-in-the-exact-same-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `float:left` to these classes `.explained_c-1, .explained_c-2, .explained_c-3`

Answer (score 2):

Missing float: left.

```
.explained_c-1, .explained_c-2, .explained_c-3 {
display: inline-block;
width: 33.3%;
height: 160px;
margin-right: -4px;
float:left;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/32E8m/3/

Answer (score 2):

I have added `float:left;` to all 3 `div` elements.
now you can add as many text as you want.

```
    <div class="explained_container">
<div class="explained_c-1">Now you can have as many text as you want</div>
<div class="explained_c-2">Div 2</div> 
<div class="explained_c-3">Div 3</div>
</div>


.explained_container{
    width: 604px;
    }

.explained_c-1, .explained_c-2, .explained_c-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 160px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    float: left;
    }

.explained_c-1 {
    background: #bbb;  
    }

.explained_c-2 {
    background: #ccc;
    }

.explained_c-3 {
    background: #ddd;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32E8m/4/

Answer (score 2):

I would just set the `vertical-align: top;` property to those classes (`.explained_c-1, .explained_c-2, .explained_c-3`) because you might not always want to float them.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/32E8m/5/

This way, you are aligning the elements to each other from the top of each of them.